# How does QED describe the electromagnetic scattering between two neutral fermions?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, magnetic-moment, neutrons

Fermions with no electric charge may carry magnetic moments e.g., the neutron. Since particles with magnetic magnetic moments interact, they're expected to scatter off each other electromagnetically. How does QED describe such a scattering?

Comment: Through a magnetic dipole interaction term in the Lagrangian.

Comment: Where do you get the dipole-dipole interaction in the QED Lagrangian? The QED Lagrangian contains an interaction term that is proportional to the electric charge and neutrons carry zero electric charge.

Comment: That's only the simplest interaction term, which describes the effect of electric charge. There are infinitely many other terms you can write down, which contribute to higher electric and magnetic moments. The particular one that adds a magnetic moment is  $i\bar{\Psi} [\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu] \Psi F_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: So the simple QED Lagrangian which is based on minimal coupling cannot explain $n$-$n$ scattering? To explain $n$-$n$ scattering one has to insert a term of the form you mention by hand and modify the QED Lagrangian. Isn't it ad hoc?

Comment: Can’t one argue that neutrons are composed of quarks, and quarks — having both charge and spin 1/2 —  have a magnetic moment arising from the minimal coupling, just like electrons do?

Comment: QED doesn't have neutral fermions so what theory are you talking about?

Comment: I agree. So what's the conclusion? All electromagnetic scattering cannot be explained by QED Lagrangian only. Or all electromagnetic interactions are not governed by the simple QED Lagrangian. Am I right?

Comment: I don’t think so.

Comment: QED is a theory for charged particles. If you want to include neutral ones, in the context of the standard model, you will need all other interactions. In particular, neutrinos can interact with light by virtual loops of charged leptons and $W^\pm$ bosons. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652628/can-photons-turn-into-neutrinos-similar-to-pair-production-of-electrons-and-p